# Arduino use Parent class Method at child class

Tags: c++, oop, parent-child

Is it possible a method defined by the parent class to use it with the child class without define it there again.
Like so:

Parent Header:

```
class parent
{ 
  public: 
    parent(uin8_t);

    void doit(uin8_t);

}
```

Parent cpp:

```
#include <parent.h>
parent::parent(uin8_t i)
{
    ...
}
void parent::doit(uin8_t i)
{
    ...
}
```

Child Header:

```
#include <parent.h>
class child : parent
{
  public:
    child(uin8_t);
}
```

Child cpp:

```
#include <child.h>
child::child(uin8_t i) : parent(i)
{

}
```

Arduino.ino

```
#include <parent.h>
#include <child.h>

child c(5);

//Setup
void setup()
{
    c.doit(4);
}'''
```

Comment: You need to use `public` inheritance: `class child : public parent` - which any basic C++ book should be explaining

Comment: Did you try this? What prevented this from working?

Comment: This isn't Arduino specific, BTW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you just have to inherit the parent with public permissions (which means to keep the current class functions' permissions).

Change:

```
class child : parent
```

To:

```
class child : public parent
```

#### Read about:

[Inheritance and access specifiers](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/115-inheritance-and-access-specifiers/)

Comment: OMG this f*cking public solved it. Thank you very much. maybe need some coffee?